# Heroku cannot find local npm package

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I have a local npm package included in my repo (I don't include the whole `node_modules` into my repo due to its over 200mb size, only specific package that I had to modify to suit my needs).

In `package.json`, local package declaration looks like this:

```
dependencies : { 
  local_package: "./my_local_package"
  ...
}
```

the error I got

```
 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
 '/app/tmp/cache/my_local_package'
```

I'm not sure if `/app/tmp/cache` is the place where my repo resides and if it's not to what should I change it.

node v4.2.1, npm  v2.14.7

Comment: before pushing to heroku, why don't u put package names ? u can keep it in git with relative local directory , but for heroku u can change and deploy it

Comment: The local dependency is included in the git repo, of course (otherwise, I wouldn't expect it to work). This feature of specifying local dependencies in `package.json` is supported since npm 2.0 and the fact that it doesn't seem to work when deploying to heroku is the exact reason why I'm asking this question :).

Comment: did you try disabling cache? `heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false` . Can you provide full deploy log?

Comment: Tried it by didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `node_modules` to git or pushing it to heroku is not recommended.

So, one possible solution would be to have your `local_package` on a separate git repo, then you could do the following to your `package.json`.

`dependencies : { 
  local_package: "git+https://example.com/local_package.git"
  ...
}`

I feel that this is a nicer solution than having only a local_package in your `node_modules` while all others are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

According to [npm documentation for local paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths), you should define it this way:

```
"dependencies" : { 
  "local_package": "file:./my_local_package"
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Even though it didn't fixed the error, it was very helpful to read the docs. I still have no idea why this step was necessary, but when I added `npm i ./local_package --save` to my deployment script it installed that package from the local directory.